# python tkinter self.master.bind() is calling function without an event

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem with tkinter self.master.bind. When I run the program below, it just calls the bind automatically! I have `self.master.bind('<left>', self.moveleft)`, It just doesn't work! It runs automatically. I have listed where the error is in a comment saying `ERROR HERE!!!`. `__init__` is working fine, `self.master` is working fine, it's just the bind, that's the only thing!

```
from tkinter import *
import time

class game_Win_Start:

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.master = root
        self.master.title('Awesome game')
        self.canvas()

    def canvas(self):
        global c
        c = Canvas(self.master, width=root.winfo_screenwidth(),
                   height=root.winfo_screenheight(), bg='black')
        c.pack()
        self.ButtonLabel()

    def ButtonLabel(self):
        global title
        title = Label(self.master, font=('arial', 50, 'bold'),
                  text='A Game', fg='orange')
        title.place(x=750, y=75)
        self.BtnStart()

    def BtnStart(self):
        global BtnStart
        BtnStart = Button(self.master, font=('arial', 45, 'bold'),
                      text='start', relief=RAISED, padx=25,
                      pady=25, bd=8, command=self.MenuDestroy)
        BtnStart.place(x=750, y=700)

    def MenuDestroy(self):
        BtnStart.place(x=2000, y=0)
        title.place(x=2000, y=0)
        GameScreen()

class gameScreen:

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.master = root
        self.drawBg()

    def drawBg(self):
        full = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        middle = full/2
        global third
        third = full/3
        third2 = third*2
        global sixth
        sixth = third/2
        c.create_line(third,0,third,1000,fill='blue')
        c.create_line(third2,0,third2,1000,fill='blue')
        c.create_rectangle(0,0,50,1000,fill='blue')
        c.create_rectangle(full,0,full-50,1000,fill='blue')
        self.spriteMe()

    def spriteMe(self):
        global sprite
        sprite = c.create_oval(0,0,50,50,fill='peru')
        c.move(sprite,sixth*3,850)
        self.master.update()
        Controls()



def GameScreen():
    gameScreen(root)

class controls:

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.master = root
        self.keyBind()

    def moveleft(self, *args):
        c.move(sprite,-608,0)
        self.master.update()
        c.update()
        time.sleep(1)
    def moveright(self, *args):
        c.move(sprite,608,0)
        self.master.update()
        c.update()
        time.sleep(1)
    def keyBind(self):                           # ERROR HERE!!!!!
        self.master.bind('left', self.moveleft())
        self.master.bind('right', self.moveright())



def Controls():
    while True:
    controls(root)


root = Tk()
game_Win_Start(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all declaring something as `foo.bind('<Event>', bar())` will immediately call the function `bar()` and set the callbacks value to the returned value of `bar()`. So if for example I set `bar()` to be the below...

```
def bar(*args):
    return print(True)
```

...then the callback would equal `print(True)`. If nothing is returned then the program will simply run the function and return `None`, meaning the callback is essentially useless (Unless this is what you wanted for some unknown reason).

Secondly, `'left'` is not an event in tkinter. `'<Left>'` however is. The brackets and capitalisation are not optional. Even if you setup the callback correctly, the callback would never be triggered as the event `'left'` doesn't exist and would never be raised.

Comment: I've heard about using `<left>`, but that never worked for me! It gave me an error. By the way, I'm using python 3.5.3.

Comment: That's because there is no event called `<left>` it's `<Left>`. The capital "L" is not optional, it has to have a capital "L".

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove the brackets from `moveleft` and `moveright`  under `keyBind` and it will not longer be automatically called. Remember, command must be a function, not the returned value of a function.